# Upgrade to Xamarin.Android 9.0.0.18 gives error: No suitable constructor found for TypefaceSpan

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Yesterday I upgraded Xamarin.Android to 9.0.0.18 on my mac, since then I get the error: No suitable constructor found for TypefaceSpan(typeface). When I upgrade upgrade to the alpha version 9.1.0.12 then I doesn't get this error anymore but in this version I'm not able to deploy my app to my phone.

If I don't want to get this error and get the app running on my device I need to upgrade clean and rebuild, downgrade and then deploy to my phone (then it works only first time). This is time consuming and doesn't look like the way to go.

The current error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGXM.png)

Anybody any idea on how to fix it

Comment: Same issue here.  Any resolution so far?

Comment: Please post your `TypefaceSpan` code.